# How to autofill the condition in conditional formatting in Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

Column A has a number 1-10.  Column B has a string I want to highlight with conditional formatting.  How do I make it so that if the number in Column A is greater than 7, the cell in the same row in Column B will automatically turn blue?

I use the conditional formatting tool for cell B1 such that, in the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option, I have ="IF($A1 > 7)", then fill the cell with blue.

But, as I drag/autofill down, the 1 in $A1 does not become A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, etc. as I want it to.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the formula to:

```
=$A1 > 7
```

And take a look at [my yoursumbuddy post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/no-ifs-in-conditional-formatting-formulas/), which explains why you don't need `IF`s in Conditional Formatting:

Comment: +1 I was too focused on the application of the conditional format that I forgot to question the formula itself xD

Comment: Thanks for the link to the post.  I wasn't aware that I don't need IFs in the Conditional Formatting tool!

Answer (score 1):

Select B1, then column B (This should make all the cells bluish except the cell B1, which is said to be the 'active' cell).

Open up conditional formatting and use the formula:

```
=IF($A1 > 7, 1)
```

You need to at least specify the value if true and there's no need to drag the conditional formatting down.